# create a cookie and check whether the cookie exists

Tags: jquery, cookies

i have created a popup at the following page:
http://suawg.osugv.servertrust.com

If i click on 18+ then it gets redirected to http://suawg.osugv.servertrust.com/default.asp

if i click on i am not 18 then it gets redirected to google.com

if i have chosen 18+ then the cookie should be created and if by mistake i again go to the that is popup page it should get redirected to the link that is when i click on 18 +

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery cookie plugin. [Get it here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

API:

```
//Getter
var value = $.cookie(title);
//Setter
$.cookie(title,hash);
```

Ex.

```
//Set the cookie
$.cookie('is18',true);

//Retrieve cookie
var is18 = $.cookie('is18');
```

You can use that simple api whenever you'd like...so when your user clicks the button, add it, then when the page is loaded, check for the cookie and handle it accordingly.

Also note that you can set expiration dates and add it across the entire site using options commands on the setter.